# How to reformat/install new SSD on MBP late2010 using OS X Internet Recovery

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ssd, disk-utility, internet-recovery

I had been saving some money to buy an SSD and finally I did. My old HDDs motor shut down so I had to replace it. I put it in the macbook all good but it isnt recognized by the system as a hard drive so I cant select it when I am trying to install the OSX from the OS X Internet Recovery option.
I think this is done because of the new SSD being NTFS (possibly from the factory) and not OSX enabled (fat) by default.

Is there a way to format (and maybe partition) the new SSD so its recognizable in internet recovery mode? 
(I dont have another macb or external drive or a clean (not infected) computer to connect the SSD and format it from there.

SSD I am using is: ADATA SP9000 256GB.

I have no backup of my old HDDs files/os/image/anything, sadly I didnt backup.

My ultimate goal is to be able to use the SSD and also install later on partition of it windows.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: For anyone in the future viewing this and having simmilar proble this is the solution:

Start up the macbook and hold down CMD+R it will start the remote isntall procedure.
Then chosoe disk utility from there partition the harddrive as you would normally using "MacOS Extended Journaled" also when you type in the size make sure you click enter or it wont get it. (I had to figure it out the hard way lol)

After that click the apply and then partition. Close that window and go back to install os x from the window before. If it doesnt show simply restart and hold down CMD+R

Comment: Make this a answer so we might like it :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone in the future viewing this and having simmilar proble this is the solution: Start up the macbook and hold down CMD+R it will start the remote isntall procedure. Then chosoe disk utility from there partition the harddrive as you would normally using "MacOS Extended Journaled" also when you type in the size make sure you click enter or it wont get it. (I had to figure it out the hard way lol) After that click the apply and then partition. Close that window and go back to install os x from the window before. If it doesnt show simply restart and hold down CMD+R